# How reliable is type inference?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference

I am just starting to pick up `typescript` and came across `type inference`.

Now according to the instructor, it's not best practice to initialize variable with `type` but to rely on `type inference` but immediately I made this error as below

```
function add(n1: number, n2: number, showResult: boolean, phrase: string) {
  const result = n1 + n2;
  if (showResult) {
    console.log(phrase + result);
  }
  return result;
}

let number1;
number1 = '5';
const number2 = 2.8;

add(number1, number2, printResult, resultPhrase);
```

From the code snippet above, it clearly let `string` slipped thru type checking and so instead, will it be a better idea if we don't rely on `type inference` but to explicitly set the type instead? Such as below

```
let number1: number;
number1 = '5';
```

and immediately we get error from above code. Below image is the proof to not trust `type inference`.

[image]

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I've added a new image to show that `type inference` slipped thru

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I've updated the screenshot again. Sorry for the confusion. I'm using 3.8.3 too

Comment: Type inference works as expected in `let number1;
number1 = '5';` - `number1` is inferred as `any`.

Comment: @zerkms: And `any` is ok to be accepted by `add` function that expecting `number`?

Comment: @Isaac yep, `any` is assignable to any other type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`number1` is typed as `any`, because nothing is assigned to it when it's declared. And `any` is, unfortunately, assignable to anything - this is why using it is strongly discouraged. With

```
function add(n1: number,
```

if you call `add` where the first argument passed is of type `any`, it'll compile.

Assigning another value to the variable *after* the variable has been declared doesn't change the type - Typescript still sees it typed as `any`.

To keep from making these sorts of mistakes, make sure to enable [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) in your tsconfig - it will throw errors when you attempt to use an `any` where a more specific type is expected.

Something else that helps is to use `const` instead of `let` - with `const`, the type will always be inferred automatically. You may occasionally need to annotate a more specific type than the inferred one, but at least the inferred type will always be something specific, and not `any`. (`const` should be preferred over `let` whenever possible anywy)

If you *do* have to use `let` - which is occasionally necessary - then either assign it a value on initialization (and type inference will work), or use a type annotation like

```
let number1: number;
```

so that it's typed properly, otherwise it'll be `any` and will cause problems.

Using a type annotation when a variable initially doesn't have anything assigned to it is perfectly fine.

Comment: "then you should use a type annotation like" --- ideally, when `let` is used - the variable should be initialised instead: `let number1 = 42;`, otherwise it says its type is `number` but the value is `undefined`, that's controversial.